# How to connect computer via Huawei C8812?

Tags: android, driver, root

I can't run android programs on android mobile phone. I need USB driver to connect. I want to connect my computer (Windows 7 32 bits) via my android phone Huawei c8812. I can't find USB driver on the Internet. And I also want to root my phone. Please Help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install `mobogenie` in your pc then On your Mobile To run drivers
http://www.mobogenie.com/product/mobogenie-pc.html